# Remove compiler warning about symbol declared but not used

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've declared some methods which occasionally get used for debugging only. For example:

```
// For debugging purposes only
{$IFDEF DBG}
procedure SaveLUTs();
{$ENDIF}
```

These methods are used rarely and only if DBG is defined. If the method is not used the following compiler warning is generated:

`[Hint] Hardware.pas(184): Private symbol 'SaveLUTs' declared but never used`

Apart from commenting out the method declaration and body, is there a way to mark `SaveLUTs` so that the compiler won't generate the warning? I still need the usual warnings to be generated, including warnings about other declared methods or variables that are not used.

Using Delphi 7 and interested in how this might be done for newer versions of Delphi as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flag the method like this :

```
{$Hints Off}
procedure SaveLUTs();
{$Hints On}
```

That will remove the hint for this procedure.

Note that `{$Hints ON}` will enable hints for the rest of the unit regardless of the previous $Hints state. Since `{$IFOPT}` doesn't work with long-named directives (At least, up to Delphi 10 Seattle...), I don't know of any way to restore the previous state.

Comment: Works just as suggested...can't upvote the answer because my reputation is too low.

Comment: One should simply not care about the previous state of hints or warnings. Just turn them off temporarily and then back on.

Comment: @StefanGlienke And why would you turn them ON after? Why ON?  Because you assume that's the setting in the project's option?  What if it isn't? If it isn't, why would we need to turn them off in the first place? Ok, fair point. But then that means your compiling directive only make sense when you build with a specific setting (`Hints ON`). If you build with hints disabled, it enabled hints for everything after this block of code, which isn't the intent. While this isn't critical, it isn't ideal either.

Comment: Point is that nobody should ever turn warnings or hints off on a project level, ever. Name a reason other than "I have to deal with code that has warnings and hints all over the place and I am too lazy or don't have time to fix them" for doing so. And even then you usually have certain units that cause them and you can still only turn them off for these units - anything else just asks for bugs sneaking into your code (less for hints though, but more so for warnings). I am still baffled by how many bugs people encounter that would cease to exist would they have watched the compiler messages.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: Just for the record, I'm all in favour of dealing with the compiler warnings and they shouldn't ever be turned off at project level! Programmers not dealing with all the warnings are indeed lazy. Ken's answer works well for my specific situation.

Comment: @KenBourassa: Just to clarify, the `{$Hints x}` compiler directives would be nested inside the `{$IFDEF DBG}` and `{$ENDIF}` block. Although this was implied, you may wish to add that to make it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to disable hints. You can do it all with your `{$IFDEF DBG}`, and have the symbol only compiled and used when the define is there. I use this frequently with code that encrypts a file and emails it when testing, because I don't want the encryption to happen or the email sent with the attachment.

```
unit Hardware;

interface

{.$DEFINE DBG}    // Remove . to include debugging code

uses
  SysUtils;

// Other procedure defs
procedure DoSomething;
procedure DoAnotherThing;
{$IFDEF DBG}
procedure SaveLuts;
{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF DBG}
procedure SaveLuts;
begin
  // Code here
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure DoSomething;
begin
  // Code here
end;

procedure DoAnotherThing;
begin
  // Code here
end;
end.
```

In the unit where you want your debugging code used:

```
procedure Main;
begin
  DoSomething;
  {$IFDEF DBG}
  SaveLuts;
  {$ENDIF}
  DoAnotherThing;
end;
```

The problem with disabling hints is that other code can sneak in inside the point where they're disabled and before they're reenabled. I don't like turning them off, because they can cause things to be missed that I didn't intend to happen.

Comment: Excellent suggestion and comments. Definitely need to be careful when manually disabling compiler warnings. However, this does call the actual method so is not the answer to the specific question. I'll mark this answer as useful and leave the original answer from KenB as the accepted answer.

Comment: @abdekker-catch: No, it does **not** call the actual method. If `DBG` is not defined, the method does not exist and is never called. (The define around the procedure declaration and implementation is never compiled and linked, and the line calling it in `Main` is also not compiled or executed). Did you **try** what I posted to see how it works? You're wrong in how you think it works.

Comment: Sorry if I have missed something, but SaveLuts is called if the DBG symbol is defined isn't it? If DBG is not defined, the method does not exist. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding in the code suggested by KenB? The {$Hints x} compiler directives would be nested inside a {$IFDEF DBG} and {$ENDIF} block, but KenB just hasn't shown this.

Comment: @abdekker-catch: There is no need for the {$HINTS} directive at all. If DBG is defined, then SaveLuts is both defined (in the interface and implementation section) and called (in the spot it's used). If DBG is **not** defined, then none of that happens and SaveLuts does not exist at all, either in the spot it's declared and defined or in the spot it's called. Of course, if what you want is the opposite, you use `{$IFNDEF DBG}` in all places. As I said, I use the same technique to remove the declaration, implementation, and use of EncryptFile and SendFile when testing code to disable those.

Comment: @abdekker-catch: You can test this quite simply yourself. Set up the code with a declaration, implementation, and single call to a procedure in a console application (it can be all in one unit). Place the `{$IFDEF DBG}` directives as I've demonstrated, and make sure debugging is enabled. Add `{$DEFINE DBG}` at the top of the unit, and build the app and see where you can and can not set breakpoints (the blue dots in the left gutter of the code editor). Now disable DBG by changing it to `{.$DEFINE DBG}` (note the dot after `{`) and build again, and see where you can set break points now.

Comment: @abdekker-catch: You'll see that either way, there are no hints or warnings generated, so there is no need to include the `{$HINTS}` directive in either case. As I said, I detest disabling hints or warnings at all, because it can cause mistakes to happen.

Comment: I suspect we're violently agreeing with each other! I know that SaveLUTs will neither be called nor generate a warning in `NDBG` mode. But in `DBG` mode it will generate a warning if it is **not** called. In my original question, I ask how to disable the warning if the method is not called. Not knowing about `{$Hints}`, I found the answer I was looking for. SaveLUTs is used rarely...even in `DBG` mode! Your comment that using `{$Hints}` are usually a bad idea is welcome, but isn't the answer to the specific question.

Comment: @abdekker-catch: I don't know about you, but I'm not being *violent* about anything. I just disagree with your accepted solution (and the problem you're trying to solve, actually). I generally don't care if I get a compiler hit or warning about something like *You have this procedure that's only enabled during debugging, you have debugging enabled, and you're not calling that procedure*. I don't like turning off hints or warnings. At the very least, just turn them off if you've defined DBG.

Comment: The phrase _violently agreeing with each other_ was just something I overheard someone else using and it seemed apt. I think you're being helpful and your comments are certainly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to change the visibility of these methods from private to protected. If they are not private, the compiler will no longer complain.

This of course has the drawback of the methods no longer being private.

Comment: Interesting observation and I can see why the compiler might make that distinction (because unknown consumers of the class *may* use the method). In my case the method really does need to be private, so the `{$Hints X}` option is fine.